# Thunk won't dispatch from child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, dispatch, thunk

I don't often post but I've been searching all day and this one's got me baffled.

I have a Redux connected component "Homepage" which is loaded as the index by React Router.

Within "Homepage"I have child component "EventCreate", which is connected to the same Redux store.

I then have a Thunk which uses Async Axios to query a GraphQL endpoint.

When I include the thunk in my "Homepage" component, and call it like so...

```
componentDidMount() {
   const { getEvent } = this.props
   const db_query = `query {
          allEvent {
            data {
              slug
              }}}`
   getEvent(db_query)
 }
```

and this is the Thunk in my main Actions file that it's calling.

```
export function getEvent(db_query) {
   return dispatch => {
      console.log(db_query)
      dispatch(getEventBegin());
      return axios({
      url: '<GRAPHQL ENDPOINT>',
      method: 'post',
      headers: { "Authorization" : <KEY> },
      data: {
        query: db_query
      }
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log("Query Result:")
      console.log(result)
      dispatch(getEventSuccess(result));
    }).catch(error => { dispatch(getEventFailure(error)); } );
  };
}
```

As you can see it calls a START and SUCCESS or ERROR action.

Here's where I'm stuck...

It runs perfectly as expected in "Homepage>" but doesn't work in "EventCreate". It fires the action, but it doesn't do any of the stuff inside the dispatch of the Thunk. No error or anything, just skips that part for some reason.

In case it's relevant I connect both to Redux like so...

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getEvent
}

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(HomePage)
```

Then in my child component...

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getEvent
}

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(EventCreate)
```

The action itself is imported like...

```
import { getEvent } from '../actions'
```

Any help would be SOOOOO appreciated.

Comment: You can leave out compose in `compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)) ` I don't see you connect EventCreate to redux: `export default connect(mapStateToProps, {eventCreate})(EventCreate)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I connect EventCreate in the same way as Homepage, which I typed but didn't explicitly state, which I'll fix.

What is the second argument you are passing to connect? Is it supposed to be EventCreate like the component name and just a lowercase typo?
If so, do I pass that instead of my dispatch?

Comment: Was supposed to be getEvent

Comment: oh gotcha. I am connecting the child component, EventCreate, already, it's able to call the Action but some reason the dispatch part won't fire.

Comment: You could try to console.log the `getEvent` after importing and in the render function of EventCreate. In the console you can click on the result and see where these functions come from. After importing it should come from action creator file and in the render it should come from react redux

Comment: I am outputting both, but when I click into info in the console where do I find the source exactly? Sorry, never done this style before

Comment: Click on the output of your console.log, the thing that you logged.

Comment: When I do that it takes me to "main.chunk.js", but I'm not sure where in this huge file is the "source" of the function

Comment: You using chrome and created the project with create-react-app? I do and that causes source maps to be created so you will go to the actual code and not the minified code.

Comment: Ok, I had to enable sourcemaps for some reason. For both cases it's saying it's loading from my Actions index file, BUT it also says that in my Homepage component, but it works fine there. I'm so confused lol

Comment: In render you're supposed to log getEvent from props.

Comment: I am doing...
    const { getEvent } = this.props
    console.log(getEvent)

In my homepage component it's now saying the render one is from Redux, but in my other component it's both Action file. So you're onto something! No idea why it's not connecting though

Comment: got it working! Problem was Thunk requires a function that return the function to be called, can't just list it in an object like regular Redux.

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      getEvent: (dbQuery) => dispatch(getEvent(dbQuery))
    }
}

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the dispatch fixed it. Not sure why exactly.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
  getEvent: (dbQuery) => dispatch(getEvent(dbQuery))
}
```

}

Comment: No it doesn't, `connect(mapStateToProps,{getEvent})` should work just fine as well. Maybe the EventCreate component called getEvent that was imported and not props.getEvent.

Comment: sorry, wrote that late at night, didn't mean to imply ALL Thunk requires it, just mine, but yeah I do wish I knew exactly what was causing the issue. All my other Redux functions work just fine so it's not lacking the props in the call.